# Prove that $\overline{X\setminus S} = X \setminus \mathring{S}$.

Tags: general-topology

Given (X,d) a metric space and $S \subset X$. I need to prove that  $\overline{X\setminus S} = X \setminus \mathring{S}$.

I did $\overline{X\setminus S} \subset X \setminus \mathring{S}$ but I've been stuck and can't seem to come up with a proof for $\overline{X\setminus S} \supset X \setminus \mathring{S}$.

I would gladly take any help you guys can give!

Comment: `\mathring{S}` produces $\mathring{S}$.

Comment: And `S^\circ` produces $S^\circ$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in X \setminus \mathring{S}$. This means that $x$ is not interior to $S$ and so for every $r>0$, $B_r(x)$ is not contained in $S$. For for each $n \geq 1$ there is $x_n \in B_{1/n}(x) \cap (X\setminus S)$. Then $x_n \to x$ and so $x \in \overline{X\setminus S}$.

(This uses the standard characterization that $F\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if for every sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}\subseteq F$ with $x_n \to x$, we necessarily have $x \in F$.)

Answer (score 2):

$x \in \overline{A}$ iff $$\forall r>0: B_r(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset\tag{1}$$

So purely by logic: $$x \in \overline{X\setminus S} \iff \forall r>0: B_r(x) \cap (X \setminus S) \neq \emptyset \iff\\ \forall r>0: B_r(x) \nsubseteq S\iff \lnot\left( \exists r>0: B_r(x) \subseteq S\right)\iff\\ \lnot (x \in S^\circ) \iff x \in X\setminus S^\circ$$

showing the equality.